# Can the unknown length of a type be a trouble to `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how multiple calls to `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` can read in data of different types of unknown lengths correctly.

For example (shown below), I write an array of integers and then a string to a file using multiple calls to `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` method.

When I read the data back using multiple calls to `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`, the length of the `int` array is unknown to the `ObjectInputStream` `oin`, so how can it correctly find the length of the array and the following `String` `Hello`?

Will the unknown length of a type ever be a problem to `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`?

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] numbers = new int[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    numbers[i] = random.nextInt();
}

// output                                                                                                                                                                  
try(FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Object.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(fout)){
    oout.writeObject(numbers);
    oout.writeObject("Hello");
} catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}

// input              
try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Object.txt");
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin)){
    int[] input = (int[]) oin.readObject();
    String str = (String) oin.readObject();
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        if (input[i] != numbers[i])
            System.out.println("The i-th numbers " + input[i] + " and " +  numbers[i] + " read and written are not equal.");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here you go, the basics of Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: For the part about object streams: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not unknown, it's stored in the stream. All necessary data is stored in the stream, to allow the `ObjectInputStream` to read it back correctly.

This is also the reason why you need to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` together. They know how to understand each other.

Comment: Thanks. Which statement stores the length of the array in the stream?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: If the file isn't created by the same program but provided from other programs, how does `ObjectInputStream` in my program figure out the length of each type (especially an array) to read?

Comment: Why do you think it matters which program wrote the data? If it was written with an `ObjectOutputStream`, then `ObjectInputStream` can read it. You don't need to be concerned about the internal implementation. If you're wondering about the size of your `input` array, it's `input.length`.

Comment: You misunderstood. I want to know how to properly use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Does `ObjectOutputStream` automatically and implicitly write length of the type of each value into a file? Is that how `ObjectInputStream` knows the length of the type of each value to read, by automatically and implicitly reading the length of the type of each value to read, when reading the file?

Comment: It writes the length of the array, so the array can be recreated easily. I'm not sure what you're talking about with "length of each value". Like I said, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: By ""length of each value", I am talking about the case when I write and read multiple values of different types into and from a file. So I said length  of "each" value. Does `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` write the length of the type of each value **automatically and implicitly**, without needing me to **explicitly** call a method to write the length specifically? Does `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` **automatically and implicitly** read the length of the type of each value, without needing me to **explicitly** call a method to read the length specifically?

Comment: I'd imagine you would have already noticed it in your tests that you don't need to explicitly do anything. You're have `(int[]) oin.readObject();` in your code after all, and you're not reading anything explicitly.